# Value filled in form not saved in database

Tags: java, database, playframework, ebean

I am trying to set a predefined value in Shop.email field in a form but it storing every field except one field i.e. email.
**Shop.java**

```
package models;

@Entity
public class Shop extends Model {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="shop_gen", sequenceName="shop_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="shop_gen")
        @Column(name="id")
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;

    @Required
    public String addressLine1;

    public String addressLine2;

    public String addressLine3;

    @Required
    public String city;

        @Required
    public String town;

        @Required
    public String phoneNumber;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="email",insertable=false, updatable=false,nullable=false)
        public Member email;

    public static Model.Finder<Long,Shop> find = new Model.Finder(Long.class, Shop.class);


}
```

**ShopController.java**

```
    package controllers;



public class ShopController extends Controller {

    static Form<Shop> shopForm = Form.form(Shop.class);


    public static Result blank() {
        String loggedInUserEmail = session("email");
        Shop shop = new Shop();

        shop.email = Member.get(loggedInUserEmail);
        shopForm.fill(shop);    

        return ok(views.html.shop.create.render(shopForm, loggedInUserEmail));



    }

    public static Result submit() {
        Form<Shop> filledForm = shopForm.bindFromRequest();

        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            String loggedInUserEmail = session("email");
            return badRequest(views.html.shop.create.render(filledForm,
                    loggedInUserEmail));
        } else {
            Shop shop = filledForm.get();
            Shop.create(shop);

            return redirect(routes.ProductController.blank());

        }
    }
}
```

**createShop.scala.html**

```
@(userForm: Form[models.Shop], user: String)

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._


@main(Html("Create Shop")) {

<fieldset>
    <legend>Add a new shop</legend>
     <p>To add a shop to this website fill in the form given below.Add as much information about your shop so the customer may know abot your shop more.</p>


@form(action = routes.ShopController.submit(), 'id -> "shopCreationForm", 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form") {

@inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "Shop Name",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine1"), '_label -> "Address Line 1",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine2"), '_label -> "Address Line 2",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine3"), '_label -> "Address Line 3",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("city"), '_label -> "City",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("town"), '_label -> "Town",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("phoneNumber"), '_label -> "Phone",'class -> "form-control")



<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Owner Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  placeholder="@user" readonly>
  </div>


    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create">
        <a href="@routes.ApplicationController.index" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>


</fieldset>
        }
        }
```

When i am submitting this form it saves every value in database except the value of email field.I am unable to understand what i am doing wrong
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `email` input field does not include a `name` attribute. Therefore, your browser can't send data correctly to the server.

You need to either use the form helper to render this input or add the `name="email"` in your `<input>` :

```
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"  placeholder="@user" readonly>
```

Comment: if i am doing name="email" then on submitting the form it loads the same page with filled values and nothing is saved in database

Comment: That might be because the form doesn't validate. As you don't display errors on the email field in your template, you can't see them. Could you show the code of the `ShopController.submit()` controller ?

Comment: I suppose that the `email` field value is not valid. You should try to output errors around your `email` input in the template. This is done automatically if you use the helpers `@input...` but because you output the field manually, you can't see them.

Comment: Giving NullPointerException on doing this `@inputText(userForm("email"), '_label -> "Owner Email" ,'id -> "createdOn",'class -> "form-control",'readonly ->"readonly",'placeholder ->user )`